# android: when exactly is a task considered background?

Tags: android, process, signals, background-process

I'm trying to kill a specific application with a specific packageName.
So this is what I'm doing: I use a service, the service listens for the foreground processes and once found the specific package, it fires off a killer activity, the killer activity is now a foreground and has just a textview, showing the correctly delivered packagename.
In the the killer activity I'm trying all of these killer commands and nothing happens.
If I press back, I go right to the untouched to-be-killed application.

```
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
             getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(mPackagename);

        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        activityManager.restartPackage(mPackagename);
        Process.killProcess(mPID);
```

In particular I can't understand: Why isn't the package being killed by:

```
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(mPackagename);
```

Is it because the target is not considered background by Android?

Any Idea people??

P.S.1: Yes, I have added these permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
```

P.S.2: Please don't tell me its something bad and I shouldn't do it. I know. Thanks :)

P.S.3: This is what happens in my service.

```
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses= activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

   for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {

 try {
                                    if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                                        if (!lastFrontAppPkg.equals((String) appProcess.pkgList[0])) {
                                                 lastFrontAppPkg = (String) appProcess.pkgList[0];

                                                 if(!lastFrontAppPkg.equals("android") && mLockedAppString.contains(lastFrontAppPkg)) {
    password to launch the lastFrontAppPkg if the pass is correct

         Log.d(TAG, "Found a locked: " + lastFrontAppPkg);


                     Intent i = new Intent();
                                                     i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PasswordCheck.class);
                                                     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                     i.putExtra(FOUND_LOCKED_PID, appProcess.pid);
                                                     i.putExtra(FOUND_LOCKED_PACKAGE, lastFrontAppPkg);
                                                     startActivity(i);
                                                     stopSelf();

                                                 }

                                         }
                                    }
                               }
                                      catch (Exception e) {
                                      //e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
```

Comment: How you'r getting The pid and mPID values ? do you get right value for process id which you want to kill ?